# Can I export my music and edited metadata from Google Music?

Tags: google-play-music

I just received an invitation to Google Music. I noticed that it's possible to edit the meta data for tracks through the website including the album art. If I wanted to switch to another music hosting service later is it possible to download all my uploaded music with updated metadata?

Answer (score 2):

Not yet.

You can visit [google.com/takeout](https://www.google.com/takeout/) to see the services which Google currently lets you export your data from.

You can also visit the "[Data Liberation](http://www.dataliberation.org)" website to see [Google projects where data can partially be exported](http://www.dataliberation.org/google).

However, neither of those list Google Music at all, and a [random comment](http://mashable.com/2011/09/06/google-voice-export/#comment-17646095) says it doesn't work yet, so the evidence is that no, you can't.
<sub>(Not being a US resident, Google Music isn't available to me, so I can't say for certain.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Here we are almost 5 years later and the answer is now... still no.

I just tried this out by downloading a song that I had uploaded and added a comment to. I was able to download it but the downloaded MP3 had no comment.

*Aside: It's disturbing that Google limits you to 2 downloads per song. It is, after all, your own music. The limit doesn't apply to Chrome, apparently, but for how long? I'm keeping backups elsewhere.*

Answer (score -1):

[Check out this Google support thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Mobile/thread?tid=46ff4c31351e4627&hl=en). Best answer there is a [user script](http://www.carballude.es/namespace/2011/08/04/72/) that lets you download songs.